# Merging Duplicate Rows with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table that contains usernames, these names are duplicated in various forms, for example, Mr. John is replicated as John Mr. I want to combine the two rows using their unique phone numbers in SQL.

[image]

I want a new table in this form after removing the duplicates
[image]

Comment: `select max(name) as Name, Phone_Number, max(Address) from tbl GROUP BY Phone_Number` if we can assume you want to grroup by phone_number   The question becomes how do you decide which "name/address 
 to use?

Comment: Or STRING_AGG instead of MAX if all names of same phone number and address should be put together

Comment: Another way is to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY phone_number ORDER BY phone_number) rec`. What you want to do is to use this select to create a temporary table. Then `truncate` or `delete` everything from permanent table. Then just `insert` as `select` from temp to perm

Comment: @JonasMetzler do you mean this way? 
select string_agg(name) as Name, Phone_Number, string_agg(Address) from tbl GROUP BY Phone_Number ? 
I'm not getting any result. Apologies, my SQL is quite rusty at the moment.

Comment: Not exactly, STRING_AGG requires a second argument (I would propose a comma here) and it should only be used on the name if you want to follow this idea. The other columns must be used in group by or max. It's not 100% clear to me, maybe you can tell us more?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I updated the question, maybe that will make the question a bit clearer to understand, thanks.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: How to create exactly this order? Or don't you care about the order of the resulting rows? The idea of the first comment here by xQbert will produce exactly those 4 rows, just not with the same order as you have shown.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with ROW_NUMBER window function.

First, you need to group the data by your unique column (Phone_Number), then sort by name.

Preparing the table and example data:

```
DECLARE @vCustomers TABLE (
    Name            NVARCHAR(25),
    Phone_Number    NVARCHAR(9),
    Address         NVARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO @vCustomers
VALUES
    ('Mr John', '234881675', 'Lagos'),
    ('Mr Felix', '234867467', 'Atlanta'),
    ('Mrs Ayo', '234786959', 'Doha'),
    ('John Mr', '234881675', 'Lagos'),
    ('Mr Jude', '235689760', 'Rabat'),
    ('Ayo', '234786959', 'Doha'),
    ('Jude', '235689760', 'Rabat')
```

After that, removing the duplicate rows:

```
DELETE
    vc
FROM (
    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Phone_Number ORDER BY Name DESC) AS RN
    FROM @vCustomers
) AS vc
WHERE RN > 1


SELECT * FROM @vCustomers
```

As final, the result:

| Name | Phone_Number | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mr John | 234881675 | Lagos |
| Mr Felix | 234867467 | Atlanta |
| Mrs Ayo | 234786959 | Doha |
| Mr Jude | 235689760 | Rabat |